# Stairs-stain color Jacobean Miniwax

Tags: wood, staining

In middle of staining stair treads, the stain isn’t dark enough and can see the wood putty underneath. Do I just go darker with next coat-different shade? Or do I need to re sand and use wood conditioner to even it out?

Comment: Tried to load pic but need to resize

Comment: Welcome to the problem of putty not accepting stain like wood does. This is an *extremely* common issue that people face all the time. Unfortunately there's no simple workaround, because one of the ideal solutions is a different filler entirely.... which you can't do now unless you're willing to dig out all the existing stuff and replace it! "Wood conditioner" won't help with this, it's too late now and wouldn't have helped initially either (it would just have made your stairs come out a lighter colour).

Comment: Yeah, essentially you have to come up with a finishing regime that is going to make the wood match the filler.  What that regime is depends on a lot more variables than you can convey easily over the internet.  The best thing to do is experiment on multiple test boards until you find something you're happy with.  Different stains or dyes, different concentrations, different application methods, time before wipe-off, and your topcoat will all change the final appearance.

Comment: @Graphus Sounds like an answer

Comment: @mmathis, perhaps, but I don't really think a worthwhile one. It looks like the OP hasn't been back since posting, if they do return I'm hoping to elicit some of the important missing details, these will allow for a good Answer that in addition to being of much greater help to the OP would be of much more value for posterity.